# How to create different table for different data value for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I am using Google App Engine webapp2 framework to build a simple website to count and collect all the bids submitted. I have read from the database called "Book" each bid.

Currently, for all the bids submitted, there is only one table to display. How can i use jinja2 to create different tables for different IssueName.

Say for example, if the IssueName=Bond1, there is table 1 collecting all the bids for bond1; if IssueName=Bond2, there is table 2 collecting all the bids for bond2

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>IssueName</th>
                        <th>RM Name</th>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Notional</th>
                        <th>Bid Time</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {% for bid in Book %}
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ bid.IssueName }}</th>
                            <th>{{ bid.RMName }}</th>
                            <th>{{ bid.CustomerName }}</th>
                            <th>{{ bid.BidPrice }}</th>
                            <th>{{ bid.Notional }}</th>
                            <th>{{ bid.BidTime }}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                {% endfor %}
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a database called Book? or a kind(table) within NDB datastore called Book? I'm assuming you meant you have a kind called book. Does your request handler look something like this?

```
from webapp2_extras import jinja2

class BidsRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        j = jinja2.Jinja2(self.app)
        self.response.write(j.render_template('bids.html', **{
            'Book': Book.query().fetch(),
        }))
```

In order to use jinja you need this in your app.yaml

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```